# vs 2017 enterprise behaving differently debug vs release builds

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, release

I'm working with a webapp that uses ASP.NET for the front end and vb.net for the backend. I worked with the app in debug mode while developing on my local machine but switched it to release mode when I was going to build it for release on my webserver. When I change it to release mode and try to build it I get thousands of errors that say things like "#object# is not defined". I went to the vb page of one of them and the imports statement for one of the .dlls at the top is grayed out. The second I switch back to debug mode the imports statement is no longer grayed out and all of the errors go away. I checked all of the release folders vs the debug folders and they both have all of the .dlls in them that they should. Please help me understand what is going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that the dll reference requires a X86 or X64 Target CPU designation.  It can be set in Debug mode and would require also changing the setting in Release mode.

You should be able to check it under Target CPU under Compile options.